# Using Ember.js fixture data, is there any way around escaping quotation marks?

Tags: ember.js

In order for the application to work I have to escape quotation marks with the backslash. Is there a way around escaping quotation marks within Ember fixture data?

```
html: "<li>\"Hello, I'm HTML!\"</li>"
```

I'm not sure where to start. Here is where I am at...

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

/****************************************************
ROUTER AND STORE SETUP
****************************************************/

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts',{path: "/"});
  this.resource('post', { path: '/:post_id'});
});

/****************************************************
HELPERS
****************************************************/

Ember.Handlebars.helper('rawhtml', function(value, options) {
  return new Handlebars.SafeString(value);
});

/****************************************************
ROUTES
****************************************************/

App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return posts;
  }
});

/****************************************************
CONTROLLERS
****************************************************/

App.PostsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    codePosts: Ember.computed.filterBy('model', 'category', 'Code')
});

/****************************************************
FIXTURES
****************************************************/

var posts = [{
category: 'Code',
id: 'cssbestpractices',
title: 'CSS Best Practices',
date: { weekday: 'Friday', month: 'November', day: '1', year: '2013' },
html: "<li>\"Hello, I'm HTML!\"</li>"
}, {
category: 'Code',
id: 'namingfiles',
title: 'Naming Files',
date: { weekday: "Thursday", month: "October", day: "24", year: "2013" },
html: "<li>Hello, I am HTML!</li>"
}, {
category: 'Code',
id: 'seo-copy-block',
title: 'SEO Copy Block',
date: { weekday: "Thursday", month: "October", day: "24", year: "2013" },
html: "<li>Hello, I am HTML!</li>"
}, {
category: 'Pizza',
id: 'pizza-delivery',
title: 'Pizza Delivery',
date: { weekday: "Tuesday", month: "November", day: "5", year: "2013" },
html: "<li>Hello, I am HTML!</li>"
}];
```

The [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/builtbymay/shhaD/). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use a single quote, this is javascript, not ember really, I like escaping more than `&apos;`

```
'<li>"Hello, I&apos;m HTML!"</li>'
```

Comment: Thanks @kingpin2k. I was hoping I wouldn't need to convert the apostrophe to HTML or use escaping. Is this expected when using JavaScript?

Comment: Yeah, it's how most strings work in most languages with special characters